# Burndown chart shows no data in TFS

Tags: tfs, scrum, alm, burndowncharts

I have on my project many PBIs and each PBI has tasks with remaining work filled in. I have finished some of my tasks, others are not started and others are in progress.

However, the burndown chart is not showing anything. Not sure exactly what I am missing to configure!

[image]

My iterations are like this:

[image]

Comment: How many days has it been since you configured it? Although the entries are dynamic for the day you will not get a burn down untill one day has passed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that the burn down needs at least 2 days of data to show something.
So basically it won't show any data the first day of the sprint but everything works 'surprisingly' on the second day. This is a longer existing issue as can seen for example on https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788378/tfs-ervice-burndown-chart-first-day-work-did-not-get-reflected-in-burndown-chart.

In my current team we will just make the first day of our sprint (when we do the sprint planning) a team day off. This will make sure that the next day the chart is showing. Closing items directly on the day of planning will lower the starting point of the burn down chart. For scrum this is not a real issue because the chart must reflect the work that needs to be done and not the work that has already been done, but for our intern processes this has been causing a lot of confusion in the past.

Comment: Hi @dennisdegroot, any chance you can clarify part of your answer for me, please?
We have tried setting our sprints (10 working days) to start the day after planning (so they are really only 9 working days in TFS). This causes the issue described above - the day of planning, and the day after, the burndown chart is empty.
Are you manually setting holidays somewhere in TFS for your planning days? Or are you setting your sprints to begin a day later than planning? (thanks!)

Comment: You are correct. We set the first day of the sprint (when we do the sprintplanning) as team day off. You can do this in the capacity tab. Sadly enough we need to do this manually every sprint.

Comment: Seems obvious when you think about it, just not when you first look at it!